# How to use PHP to load html file to replace part of a page in an all ajax site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

So I am trying to create an entirely ajax site that still enables the usage of the back button and external links. I created a .htaccess file and now I have a get array that I can process in my index.php file. The issue is that I have no idea how to make the repair.html replace the existing section.center html code using PHP. I do it in jQuery everywhere else but obviously this is php. Just give me a push in the right direction, I know I'm close!! You can view the site here: http://techxpertschico.com

**Here is output :**

```
Array ( [parameters] => repair )
```

**This is my php :** I'm not sure what to put in for the comments.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['parameters']))
{
    print_r($_GET);
    if($_GET['parameters'] == "repair")
    {
        // load repair.html into section.center
    }
}
?>
```

**Here is the jquery :**  I normally load my html files using ajax requests. I use history.js to manage the url hashes.

```
$('.ajaxAnchor').on('click', function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('section.center').html(data);
    });
    var shortened = url.substring(0,url.length - 5);
    History.pushState({state:1}, shortened, shortened);
});
```

**Example section.center from the home page load:**

```
<section class="center">
            <p>
                Welcome to TechXperts! We offer training and repair for all of your tech devices, but our primary goal is to listen! We know that technology is frustrating so we give you the chance to let us know what your problem is. We will offer the necessary training, or repair to help you have fun using your devices, the way it should be! We feel that is our responsibility to the community as the local TechXperts!
            </p>
            <a href="https://techxpertschico.youcanbook.me/" class="appointmentButton">Book Appointment Now</a>
            <a href="quote.html" class="appointmentButton">Get a Quote</a> 
            <img src="images/random/FrustratedFlyers.png">
            <h3 style="display: inline; position: relative; bottom: 150px;">Friendly staff always available to answer questions!</h3>
            <div style="display: inline; position: relative; left: 310px; bottom: 100px;">
                <img src="/images/random/Apple.png" width="100px">
                <img src="/images/random/Windows8-1.png" height="80px">
                <img src="/images/random/Andoird.png" width="100px">
                <img src="/images/random/check.png" width="100px">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: You *are* aware that PHP runs at the server, and Javascript runs in the client's browser, right?

Comment: I am aware, which is why I'm not sure how to approach this problem from the design of my site

Comment: You can't make an AJAX call from PHP. You can do things that have the same effect, but It's not clear from your question whether even that's necessary. Can't you just `include()` the HTML file?

Comment: It was a terrible title sorry for that guys. I edited the question title. I need to change the index.php's section.center using the file repair.html. I know this can't be difficult but for some reason I am having a hard time with the approach. Maybe my mind is just frazzled because I desperately want to finish this lol. Tunnel vision at the end of a project I suppose!

Comment: So, you want to call into some PHP code on the server, which will generate and return some HTML, which you then use to overwrite some existing HTML? Do I have that correct?

Comment: it will not generate the html it will only return it. I have an index.php file and the center content changes on each button click but the html that is in the center already exists. This is all purely for functionality of the back button and linking. If you click around you can see that it already has the content. http://techxpertschico.com

Comment: Sorry, not going to visit some random website to see what you're doing. Your question needs to contain enough of your code for someone to reproduce the problem, or link to a known site like jsFiddle. That being said, the answer will be the same regardless of whether the content is static or generated. I'll post something shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to return the contents of repair.html to the client if the query string has a matching query string.

in php you do this with an include

```
if($_GET['parameters'] == "repair")
{
    include 'repair.html'
}
```

Comment: I want to replace the contents of section.center with the contents of repair.html. Can I do that directly in php or should I return the entire file like you are suggesting and then use jquery to replace?

Comment: So Bryan this is working wonderfully except for the fact that the included file's html always is at the top even if I put the include lower in the document tree. How can I echo it lower on the page?

Comment: that is handled on the client side in your javascript.  the easiest way to do that is throw a div tag on your page where ever you want the content to b placed such as <div id="repair-section"></div>

Comment: well its strange because my css handles my positioning correctly when you navigate to repair.html, but when you throw it in as a link and try to go there it changes the orientation. I'm assuming it has to do with the include since it works fine when I'm not loading it that way. You can observe it here if you're not scared of checking out my random site ;) http://techxpertschico.com/repair. In fact I'll post the code of repair.html

Comment: nvm fixed. You're awesome. All I did is replace my static section.center content with the script and put the logic in there to include the appropriate file. I knew it was simple... just couldn't think it through. Thanks a ton for the simple answer I was looking for. I overcomplicated it far too much!

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is a request done by the browser, so it can not be made via a server-side script (PHP). You can generate JS code via php (echo or something like that) and send it to browser if you absolutny must make an ajax call there.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you get array value in index.php then you page is already loading. 
might me no need to use ajax here .

If ajax make your life easier then solution is here:- 
Add script in index.php. Call ajax onload of page when you get appropriate value in parameter.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['parameters'])) {
    print_r($_GET);
    if ($_GET['parameters'] == "repair") {
        // load repair.html into section.center
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var param = '<?php echo $_GET['parameters']; ?>';

                if (param !== "undefined" && param.length > 0) {
                    // ajax call for load repair.html into section.center 
                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

**Alternate solution:-**

Why not simply this:-

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['parameters'])) {
    if ($_GET['parameters'] == "repair") {
        ?>
        <section class="center">
            <p>
                Welcome to TechXperts! We offer training and repair for all of your tech devices, but our primary goal is to listen! We know that technology is frustrating so we give you the chance to let us know what your problem is. We will offer the necessary training, or repair to help you have fun using your devices, the way it should be! We feel that is our responsibility to the community as the local TechXperts!
            </p>
            <a href="https://techxpertschico.youcanbook.me/" class="appointmentButton">Book Appointment Now</a>
            <a href="quote.html" class="appointmentButton">Get a Quote</a> 
            <img src="images/random/FrustratedFlyers.png">
            <h3 style="display: inline; position: relative; bottom: 150px;">Friendly staff always available to answer questions!</h3>
            <div style="display: inline; position: relative; left: 310px; bottom: 100px;">
                <img src="/images/random/Apple.png" width="100px">
                <img src="/images/random/Windows8-1.png" height="80px">
                <img src="/images/random/Andoird.png" width="100px">
                <img src="/images/random/check.png" width="100px">
            </div>
        </section>
        <?php

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: well because it isn't going to be the same code each time in the section.center

Comment: Okay . then My first solution will work for you. Only thing in `var url = $(this).attr('href');` will not work for you as we are calling onload of page. you should write exact id to get href here.

Comment: I'm in the process of implementing it now! I'll let you know how it goes. I wasn't expecting to be so brute force as to echo a script... but it works!

Comment: Thanks for you're help! Turns out the #include works better for what I want because all I have to do is include a php script with that logic right inside of the section.center that constantly changes!